# Состояние БД в MySQL

Tags: mysql, обработка-ошибок

Вот здесь http://prntscr.com/ihrfn9 и ниже есть значения выделенные красным. Это означает, что они выходят за рамки допустимой нормы?

Можно ли утверждать, что все параметры ниже имеют отклонения из-за неправильно написанного движка? И можно что-либо изменить сейчас без правки самого движка и где это меняется?

- Handler read rnd **11.9 M** Количество запросов на чтение строки, основанных на её позиции. Большое значение переменной может быть обусловлено частым выполнением запросов, использующих сортировку результата. Видимо, выполняется много запросов, требующих полного сканирования таблиц, или имеются объединения, неиспользующие индексы надлежащим образом.
- Handler read rnd next **1.2 G** Количество запросов на чтение следующей строки из файла данных. Данное значение будет высоким, если выполняется много сканирований таблиц. Обычно это означает, что таблицы проиндексированы ненадлежащим образом или запросы не используют преимущества индексов.
- Opened tables **875** Количество открытых таблиц. При большом значении переменной рекомендуется увеличить размер кэша таблиц.
- Qcache lowmem prunes **10.1 M** Количество запросов, удалённых из кэша для освобождения памяти под кэширование новых запросов. Может помочь при настройке размера кэша запросов. Кэш запросов использует стратегию LRU (неиспользуемые длительное время страницы заменяются новыми) при принятии решения об удалении запроса из кэша.
- Select full join **200** Количество запросов-объединений без использования индексов. Если значение не равно 0, рекомендуется проверить индексы таблиц.
- Created tmp disk tables **349.9 k** Количество временных таблиц, автоматически созданных сервером на диске во время выполнения SQL-выражений. Если значение Created_tmp_disk_tables велико, следует увеличить значение переменной tmp_table_size, чтобы временные таблицы располагались в памяти, а не на жестком диске.
- Innodb buffer pool reads **839** Количество логических операций чтения, которые InnoDB не смог выполнить из буферного пула и использовал постраничное чтение.
- Sort merge passes **21** Количество выполненных алгоритмом сортировки проходов. При большом значении следует увеличить значение переменной sort_buffer_size.

Comment: *Это означает, что они выходят за рамки допустимой нормы?* Ну нам же не видно, за секунду это или за неделю...

Comment: Если значение у переменной большое, то оно подсвечивается красным,  - в этом случае MySQL сам подсказывает окрашивая в красный, тем самым давая понять - "обратите внимание, здесь что-то не так". Это и есть выход из нормы. В моем представлении, есть промежуток, в котором БД и сайт отлично работают, а есть предел, где БД "чувствует" себя уже не так хорошо. - Аналогия длительная езда автомобиля с постоянной скоростью 90км/ч, против 200 км/ч.

Comment: *MySQL сам подсказывает окрашивая в красный* MySQL в принципе неспособен хоть что-то подкрашивать. это делает программа. которая получает от сервера данные и отображает их. На основании каких критериев она это делает, нам неизвестно...